# I want to change this callback function to async/await, but I don't know how to change this

Tags: node.js, async-await, callback

```
User.findOne({ email: email })
.then((savedUser) => {
  if (savedUser) {
    return res
      .status(422)
      .json({ error: "user already exists with that email" });
  }
  bcrypt.hash(password, 12).then((hashedpassword) => {
    const user = new User({
      email,
      password: hashedpassword,
      name,
      pic,
    });

    user
      .save()
      .then((user) => {
        res.json({ message: "saved successfully" });
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  });
})
.catch((err) => {
  console.log(err);
});
});
```

I'm studying async/await by changing some callback function to async/await. This code has two catch error but I don't know how to change this code to async/await.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const saveUser = async (email,password,name,pic)=>{
try{
 const user = new User({
      email,
      password: await  bcrypt.hash(password, 12),
      name,
      pic,
    })

 const savedUser = await User.save()
 return savedUser 
 }catch(error){
 throw new Error(error)
 }
}

const findUser = async (email)=>{
try{
 const user = await User.findOne({ email: email })
 return user
 }catch(error){
  throw new Error(error)
 }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much. I revised my code by your answer.

Comment: Just decorate your function with an async key word and you can use await with any function that returns a promise. enclose everything in a try catch block to catch the rejected promise or any exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

A key thing to remember is that you can `await` on `Promise` (the `async` keyword is like a decorator that force a function to return a `Promise`).

The following methods returns promise so you can use `await`

- `User.findOne(...)`
- `bcrypt.hash(...)`
- `user.save()`

the refactored code will look something like this:

```
async function functionName(...) {

    try {
        const savedUser = await User.findOne({ email: email });
    }
    catch (e) {
        //...
    }
    if (savedUser) {
        return res
            .status(422)
            .json({ error: "user already exists with that email" });
    }

    const hashedpassword = await bcrypt.hash(password, 12)
    const user = new User({
        email,
        password: hashedpassword,
        name,
        pic,
    });

    try {
        await user.save();
    }
    catch (e) {
        return res
            .status(422)
            .json({ error: "...ERROR..." });
    }
    res.json({ message: "saved successfully" });

}
```